# can i generate a mysql trigger without a definer clause?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Question is dead simple. I want to add a trigger to my database, any simple one like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_user_update BEFORE UPDATE ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.user_id = NEW.old_user_id_column;
END
```

Unfortunately when i do that i always get a `DEFINER` clause in the dump with host and username, which is very troublesome because i need to use this on different environments on which this definer will be completely different?
Is there any workaround?
I guess this question could be asked: how to use the same query trigger in multiple environments?
(im using rails)

I know i can just remove the definer part from the schema manually, but it will cause problems to my coworkers who are going to run a migration and still get the clause in their schema

Comment: Many (the most part of) CREATE DDL statements and according SHOW statements differs. This is a norma. Each created object has a lot of attributes which MUST have a value. If this value have default one then its assigning may be skipped in CREATE, and default value will be used, if no default value then this attribute specifying is compulsory. For example, you may skip column nullability but cannot skip column datatype.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot create a trigger without the definer clause.

As mysql documentation on [create trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) says:

> If the DEFINER clause is omitted, the default definer is the user who executes the CREATE TRIGGER statement. This is the same as specifying DEFINER = CURRENT_USER explicitly.

So, even if you omit the definer, mysql will give you one. So, you either create the same mysql user across the different environments or you save the trigger code with `DEFINER = CURRENT_USER`. Unfortunately, when you run the create trigger code, mysql will substitute the current user's name into the definer clause.